# Replay UDP Packet Capture

Tags: c#, udp, packet-capture

I have a UDP packet capture which I captured using wireshark on network N1. This capture     contains packets going from Port 4000 on IP address IP1 to Port 4000 on IP address IP2.

I am now replaying these packets using Colasoft Packet Player on network N2, sending the packets from IP address IP3 to IP address P4.

Since I am replaying the packets, I assume that they will sent from and received on port 4000. This has been confirmed by capturing the replayed packets with wireshark.

However, I am unable to see any of these packets in a UDP server that I wrote in C# (which, due to company confidentiality reasons, I am unable to post here). To eliminate any suspicion of error on the side of my code, I downloaded the following code from an online example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

// SERVER.CS
// This is a simple UDP server that receives a UDP datagram containing a random word to a server on the local computer
// usage server.exe [PORT], where [PORT] is the sever UDP port number of the local PC

namespace UDPLocalServer
{
    class ProgramServer
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                if (args.Length != 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("USAGE: client.exe [PORT] [MESSAGE]");
                Environment.Exit(1);
                }

            byte[] message = new byte[128];

            String server_name         = Dns.GetHostName();             // Get the name     of the sever
            IPHostEntry server_host    = Dns.GetHostEntry(server_name); // Internet host address information
            IPAddress server_ip        = server_host.AddressList[0];    // IP address of the server
            IPEndPoint server_endpoint = new IPEndPoint(server_ip, Convert.ToInt16(args[0])); // IP and PORT pairing of the server

            // Creates an IPEndPoint to capture the identity of the client when we'll use the Socket.ReceiveFrom Method
            IPEndPoint remote_endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 4000);   // IP and PORT pairing of the client

            Socket server_udp_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            // Bind the Socket to the local endpoint
            server_udp_socket.Bind(server_endpoint);

            // Receive message from the remote local client
            EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)remote_endpoint;
            server_udp_socket.ReceiveFrom(message, ref ep);

            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(message));
            Console.WriteLine(ep.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(message this program is not able to show me any udp communication, while wireshark is showing me incoming packets.
```

I really don't understand why this is happening, and I'd appreciate any help on the matter.

Thank you

Comment: Does the ColaSoft player chance the source address from IP1 to IP3?  Does it recalculate the checksums?  Does your program work if you send UDP packets to it directly?

Comment: I don't think ColaSoft player changes IP addresses. I had to spoof some IPs on N2. I also doubt that it recalculates checksums. The program works as expected and will pick up on UDP packets sent directly to it

Comment: What about the MAC address? Does the replayer change the MAC addresses too?